# Replace with * in string VBa excel

Tags: string, replace

Is there a way to replace with * in the replace function of a string?

Ex.
String Text =207.800003,209.399994,207.199997,208.800003,208.800003,240477,2023-06-23,null,null,null,null,null,null,2023-06-14,207.399994,207.600006,196.899994,199.000000,199.000000,1157604,2023-06-15

I want to replace null,null,null,null,null,null,2023-06-14 with a comma ","
but the "date" changes so i can not do:
Text = Replace(Text, ",null,null,null,null,null,null,2023-06-23" ",")

Is there i way to do something like this in replace?

Text = Replace(Text, ",null,null,null,null,null,null,*,"  ",")

/M